# Bootstrap OverlayTrigger with right click?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, overlay, react-bootstrap

In React is it possible to trigger an `<OverlayTrigger>` with a right click?

I didn't see this option in the documentation.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#overlay-trigger-props